# Updating the card.io plugin for phonegap 2.0 and above

Tags: phonegap-plugins, card.io

I am trying to upgrade the Card.io phonegap plugin to work for phonegap 2.0 or above.  I've never upgraded a phonegap plugin before and am looking for some direction before I start the project.  Who can help?

Comment: I'd recommend going incrementally. What is the first piece that needs upgrading? (I.e. where does the integration fail?) Then look for how to upgrade that piece. Ask a specific question about that piece -- that'll attract more help. Repeat until the whole thing is upgraded. :)

Answer (score 0):

the updated PhoneGap plugin for Card.io can be found here https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK-PhoneGap

hope it helps!

thanks.